# SignalR: Mock IHub with moq framework and test his method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, signalr, mstest, signalr-hub

I try to test my custom RepositoryHub which inherits base class Hub ([implements IHub interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.ihub%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)). I mocked all necessary properties of IHub and one his method call which i want to test. Method call was imitated as call from derived custom class RepositoyHub:

`hubMock.Setup(p => p.OnConnected()).Returns(new RepositoryHub().OnConnected());`

The problem is that method  don't have access to mocked IHub fields.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Is_OnConnected_Successive_When_Instances_is_Absent_And_User_Authenticated()
    {
        try
        {
            var connectionId = "1";

            var request = new Mock<IRequest>();
            request.Setup(s => s.User.Identity.Name).Returns(user + "&" + server + "&" + password + "&" + level);
            request.Setup(s => s.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

            var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext>();
            var mockGroupManager = new Mock<IGroupManager>();
            var mockHubCallerContext = new Mock<HubCallerContext>(request.Object, connectionId);

            var hubMock = new Mock<IHub>(); 
            hubMock.Setup(p => p.Groups).Returns(mockGroupManager.Object);
            hubMock.Setup(p => p.Context).Returns(mockHubCallerContext.Object);
            hubMock.Setup(p => p.Clients).Returns(mockClients.Object);
            //Mock virtual method call
            hubMock.Setup(p => p.OnConnected()).Returns(new RepositoryHub().OnConnected()); 


            var r = hubMock.Object.OnConnected();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {       
            throw;
        }
    }
       // Here method which i want to test with mocked IGroupManager, HubCallerContext and IHubCallerConnectionContext

    public partial class  RepositoryHub: Hub
    {
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            try
            {
                var userProfile = new UserProfile(Context.User); 
                //NullReference exception Context == null, but why i got it if mocked
                //HubCallerContext in test method

                Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userProfile.ServerUrl);
                // and other useful actions 

                return base.OnConnected();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.TraceError(String.Format(" Hub: OnConnected() {0}", ex.Message));
                throw;
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figure out easy way as for me. Thanks for attention!

```
            var repository = new RepositoryHub(){ Context = mockHubCallerContext.Object,
                                                  Clients = mockClients.Object,
                                                  Groups = mockGroupManager.Object };

            var r = repository.OnConnected();
```

For  JohnB, answer for your last question:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Is_OnConnected_Successive()
{
    const string connectionId = "1";
    dynamic groupName = new ExpandoObject();

    var IsSendMessageCalled = false;

    groupName.sendMessage = new Action<object>((message) =>
    {
        IsSendMessageCalled = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("sendMessage was called, message:  {0}", message);
    });

    var request = new Mock<IRequest>();
    request.Setup(s => s.User.Identity.Name).Returns(user + "&" + server + "&" + password + "&" + level);
    request.Setup(s => s.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext>();
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.Group("groupName")).Returns((ExpandoObject)groupName);

    var mockGroupManager = new Mock<IGroupManager>();
    var mockHubCallerContext = new Mock<HubCallerContext>(request.Object, connectionId);

    var hub = new RepositoryHub()
    {
        Context = mockHubCallerContext.Object,
        Clients = mockClients.Object,
        Groups = mockGroupManager.Object
    };

    var testMethod = hub.OnConnected();
    Thread.Sleep(threadSleepTime);
    //or testMethod.Wait();

    Assert.IsTrue(IsSendMessageCalled);
}
```

Let suggest, here you call your sendMessage(message) method:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    Hub.Clients.Group("groupName").sendMessage("Hello ! for groupName group ");
}
```

Comment: Hi: I found your post and answer very enlightening. I'm running into an additional issue. I followed your pattern. I'm having difficulties sending messages off my mocked group. So the following call: Clients.Group(groupName).sendMessage(message) fails as the Clients.Group() call returns null. Did you encounter this or have any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnB Hello! Yes, i did. I added answer for your question above

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. It was definitely useful. I find myself wishing that the SignalR library itself was a little more open so that I could actually see the Client & Group collections directly for investigation during Unit Testing. I would like to be able to set up a unit test involving multiple hubs and clients. Have you had any experience with that? I will write a new post regrading that. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnB SignalR is open, here you can download source code [link](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR). I don't have experience with testing multiple Hubs, but i can't imagine any issue which could be encountered on your way. If you need the same setup, you already have it(i.e. mocked Group, Clients, Context). What do prevent you to create another Hub type instance and assign the same mocked setup ?

Comment: I have the SignalR source downloaded. I didn't see anything that might help figure out unit testing/mocking multiple clients/connections on the same mocked hub. The way I have the HubCallerContext (hub.Context) mocked up, it is associated with a single connection instance.

Comment: @JohnB Use [**Tasks**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. For each task use difference context setup, if you really need to reach real cases.

Comment: 6 years later...this answer saved me